# Do I need a free builder in order to build a Builder's Hut?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'll add 500 gems to my account and build a Builder's Hut, however both my builders are building something at the moment. I'm not sure if I need one to be free (as in not building something).

Do I need a free builder in order to build a Builder's Hut?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a free builder.

You just have to place the Builder's Hut, and it will be built immediately, just like walls, but unlike walls, Builder's Huts don't require a free builder.

Comment: Tested this out 15 minutes ago, so not a speculation or smth.